# VScode and WinPython

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I try to use WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5 on Windows 10 Pro with VScode. Winpython is installed in C:\Users\Public\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5. In the user settings file I have, but I cannot see WinPython in list of available python intepreters and python environments. What could be wrong. I tried also to use "\"

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",

    "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/Public/WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5/python-3.6.3.amd64/python.exe"
}
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Unfortunately not any and all python interpreters will be listed. Only the most popular locations will be searched and listed. We search the registry (as per pep 514), conda installs, and local virtual environments). We can make some changes to include Winpython as well, please create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Don. From your response I conclude, that basically the way I wanted to include WinPython is okay, but VScode is currently not ready for WinPython.

Comment: Thanks A.A. Yes I did read and do use python enironments. The reason I wanted to use WinPython is because I have the latest version of python and I does not work yet with the latest version o f matlibplot. In Winpython I have a huge package with all the modules I want working perfectly together.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify path to the folder, not to python.exe. Like `WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\\python-3.6.3.amd64`

See also https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/784

Answer (score -1):

Here is a procedure, to have a movable vscode, next to your movable WinPython 
 https://github.com/winpython/winpython_afterdoc/blob/master/docs/installing%20VScode.ipynb